# What diagramming methodology should I use to document an existing system?

Tags: architecture, uml, reverse-engineering, diagram

I have been asked to participate in the documentation of a complex existing system (which naturally has no existing documentation).

Relevant details to capture will be:

- Hostnames, IP addresses and networks
- Composition of clusters
- Names of software packages
- Paths of configuration files
- Some key configuration values
- Sequence of interaction between different hosts and services on those hosts
- Information passed between different components
- Ownership of systems and subsystems

I would like to use a standardised approach, or at least some best practices, so I'm looking at using things like UML deployment diagrams and component diagrams, but I'm new to UML so I'm not sure which is best. I'd really like to use one type of diagram that could capture everything, but if not then as few as possible.

I guess some of the relevant information may not fit on a diagram in which case I'm wondering what type of document would contain the detail.

What should I produce?

Answer (score 0):

You will confuse the reader if you cram too many concerns into the same diagram. A better approach is to use multiple diagrams (plus associated text and tables).

I would suggest to have, at the very least:

- a view that describes how components interact with each other at run-time, with a description of the interfaces that connect them. That is best associated to a description of the responsabilities of each component.
- a view that describes how components are deployed.
- a view that describes how the various modules are built.

The various types of UML diagrams may be used for each purpose. Personally, I tend to rely more on ad-hoc diagrams, with images and colors. I find UML diagrams too dull. Of course, when you use custom diagrams, it is important to always provide a key or legend box.